# Asp.Net Core Razor Pages Failed AJAX request after migrating to Version 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

AJAX requests are no longer working after migrating from .NET Core 2.1 to 3.1.

#### Previous Code

AJAX call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Controller/ControllerA",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        Name: name,
        Value: value
    }),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "json",
    success: { ...},
});
```

Model

```cs
public class ItemModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Action

```cs
[HttpPost("ControllerA")]
public async Task<JsonResult> ControllerA([FromBody] ItemModel item)
{
...
}
```

Error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
> <>8__1.IteModel was null.

This code has been working fine on version 2.1, but it stopped after migration.

Any idea?

Comment: Between dotnet core 2 and 3 the deserialisation engine was changed from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json. You can readd Newtonsoft.Json as deserializer by adding the following in your startup: services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(); after installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson. I dont know but suspect this can be the reason for your problem.

Comment: @Achtung Indeed installing Microsoft-NewtonsoftJSON solved this!

Answer (score 2):

Solved by installing "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJSON" and adding the following to startup.cs

```
            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
            services.AddRazorPages().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```